# I need to pass arguments from outer function to inner function

Tags: javascript, function

I need to use variable arguments to inner function.

I have this function that I cannot change:

```
function SUM() { 
  var res = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    res += (arguments[i]==null?0:arguments[i]);
  }
  return mSum(res);
}
```

Well because this function sometimes returns extra decimal values, I want to wrap it into a function like

```
function MySUM( return parseFloat(SUM().toFixed(10))    );
```

the problem is that SUM function cannot read "arguments" of outer function that calls it, and I don't know how to pass this arguments from mySUM to inner SUM function. What I expect is some like this

```
function MySUM( return parseFloat(SUM(arguments).toFixed(10))    );
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: please add an example of your array.

Comment: What is the original `SUM()` function supposed to return?

Comment: So you're adding a wrapper to another wrapper? Can you change `mSum()`? You shouldn't need to check for `null` since js will treat it like 0 in this case. `res += arguments[i];` should give you the same result for `res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spread the arguments using the `...` operator, send them to the `SUM` function:

```
function MySUM() {
    return parseFloat(SUM(...arguments).toFixed(10));
    // Here --------------^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
function MySUM(arguments) {
    return parseFloat(SUM(arguments).toFixed(10))
}
```